# slack files & url with headers

Tags: python, http-headers, slack, slack-block-kit

I'm building a slack bot (python/slack-bolt).
Trying to share a private image within the app home tab.

The home tab is genereted using client.views_publish.

```
{
   "type": "image",
   "title": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "test image",
             },
   "image_url": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/<private_ref>/test.jpg",
   "alt_text": "test"
                    },
```

Now image_url isn't valid as this is a private file.
But the file can be accessed via the requests with headers:
e.g. this downloads the file correctly:

```
curl https://files.slack.com/files-pri/<private_ref>/test.jpg --header "Authorization: Bearer <bot_token>" --output test.jpg
```

How can the url for an image be constructed for the slack blocks so the private image is available to the bot homepage?

Comment: Hey! Have you found a solution for your problem that doesn't imply making the image public?

Comment: never did succeed yet unfortunately, and lost interest after it got too difficult... will revisit again

Answer (score 0):

You might have to make the file public shared.

This can be done using following api:

 https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL